# What do you expect to happen when you click, Reset All?

Tags: website-design, navigation, user-behavior, user-expectation

[image: A header with a Date Picker, Filter, Reset All, Sort, Export and Email option]

Above we have a Date Picker, Filter, Reset All, Export, Email and Sort option.

The function of **Reset All** applies to the Date Picker, Filter and the sort arrows below.

So what do you expect to happen when you click, **Reset All**?
Is this the best way to go about ordering all these actions?

Comment: What is the difference between "Date Picker" and the date with arrows around it? Are they tied to each other?

Comment: I would expect my selections in `date picker` and `filter by` to be cleared...

Comment: @DasBeasto Yes they are. When you select a date in the "Date Picker" drop down, it updates in the date with the arrows around it.  The arrows can be used to easily go to the next or previous day.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be treating the site members as study participants (asking what we expect) rather than UX practitioners (asking about a best practice in this situation).

Comment: @jlmakes, thank you for your thoughts, thats exactly what I intended the Reset All button to target. I also need to associate it with the sort arrows below. Maybe its something the users can learn.

Answer (score 1):

Given the picture you provided, I would expect the large date text ("Sun, 25 Oct 2015") as well as any changes in the Date Picker and Filter By to return to the values they were when the page was loaded. I would, however, not expect the table sort toggles to be reset.

This is because of your use of white space and proximity as well as font style, the "reset all" button is the same font style, both size and color, as Filter By and Date picker and appears to be almost hugging the two selectors. Your mind can almost create a box around the elements to group them together like so:

[image]

For that reason I would not expect them to have any effect on the table's sort toggles. I would not even expect it to have an effect on the large date text "Sun, 25..." if it we're not clarified that it was the same tool as the date picker.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. Based on your response, it seems clear that the Reset All button is associated with the Date Picker and Filter. I agree I do need to make it clear the Sort arrows would be reset as well. As for the large date text, its there as a reminder of what you are viewing. A single date or date range. So I would hope that its clear to the user that it would reset to the current day.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "Reset All" is not visibly connected to any of the dropdowns I would say it returns the top bar to the default state. One suggestion is perhaps to hide the Export and Email button under a share icon. I would also make the Reset All into a button kinda like the Export CSV but with a nice reddish tone to indicate a "irreversible action".

Comment: Great idea! I was thinking of making a tools button and putting the Export and Email options under that. It would declutter and maybe make things more clear. Making the actions irreversible is a great ideas as well. I will run that by my team for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since Reset All has the same color as Date Picker and Filter By I expect it to affect these two fields. However, I'm not sure because there is no other visual grouping of Reset All with these fields. Also taking into account it has the same color as other elements, including the buttons, I really can only guess what it will do.

That said, this design needs some improvement. However, it's really difficult to advise what can be done without knowing the use cases or, at least, what Reset All *should* do. Though, I would like to note, if Reset All affects filters or entire top line, it should look differently. All other options set some kind of filters, reset cancels them, so it cannot look the same. I should be able to separate it visually from the rest.

Comment: I should have given more information in my original question. You are right, the Reset All button should only reset the date picker and filter. But it should also reset the sort by arrows. Adding another color is something I could possible do to make this distinction clear. Maybe making the two button on the right a different color so that the blues are associated with "Reset."